# TestNG running sibling tests before child tests

Tags: testng

I'm writing some tests using Selenium and TestNG where, I have one starting point (login screen) which forks into different scenarios. For example the following tests

- login tests

  - Home Page tests

    - Select Option 1

      - Option 1 tests
    - Select Option 2

      - Option 2 tests

The problem I'm having is the TestNG is running "Select Option 1" and then "Select Option 2" before running the child tests for "Select Option 1". What I want is for TestNG to run the tests in a depth first order rather than breadth first.

LoginTestNG.java

```
@ContextConfiguration(value = {"classpath:selenium-test.xml"})
public class LoginTestNG extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

  @Test(groups = {"connect"})
  public void connect(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("Connect to URL");
  }

  @Test(groups = {LOGIN_FAILURE_GROUP}, dependsOnGroups = {"connect"}, priority = 0)
  public void loginFailure(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("Login failure");
  }

  @Test(groups = {LOGIN_SUCCESS_GROUP}, dependsOnGroups = {"connect"}, priority = 1)
  public void loginSuccess(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("Login Succes");
  }
}
```

Option1TestNG.java (Option2TestNG.java at the moment is a copy of Option1TestNG.java with the numbers changed)

```
@ContextConfiguration(value = {"classpath:selenium-test.xml"})
public class Option1TestNG extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

  @Test(groups = { "OPTION_1_GROUP" }, dependsOnGroups = { LoginTestNG.LOGIN_SUCCESS_GROUP })
  public void selectOption1(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("Option 1");
  }

  @Test(groups = { APPLICANT_FAILURE}, dependsOnGroups = {CREDIT_REPORTS_GROUP}, priority = 0)
  public void submitApplicantWithoutSettingFields(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("Option 1 submit applicant no fields set");
  }

  @Test(groups = { APPLICANT_SUCCESS}, dependsOnGroups = {CREDIT_REPORTS_GROUP}, priority = 1)
  public void submitApplicantSettingFields(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("Option 1 submit applicant success"); 
    System.out.println("Go back to home page");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing (and using) custom [Method Interceptors](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) is the way to have greater control over the order of execution.